# GLFW with CMake on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, cmake, glfw

I am having trouble using GLFW on my mac.
I am currently using CMake and visual studio code on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7. I am currently using GLFW 3.4.0.

But i just keep getting all these error messages from GLFW. There seems to be a problem with the .m files. I keep geting error messages like these:

```
GLFW/src/nsgl_context.m:81:5: error: expected expression
@autoreleasepool {
^

GLFW/src/cocoa_init.m:80:5: warning: 'UseDictionary' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.8 [-Wdeprecated-declarations] 
NSDictionary* bundleInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

GLFW/src/cocoa_monitor.m:228:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'screen'; did you mean 'strlen'?
monitor->ns.screen = screen;
```

I have added GLFW as a submodule from git, so it should be up to date.

These are just a few examples, but i don't know how to fix this.

EDIT EDIT:

My CMakeLists.txt file currently looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.0-rc3)

include(FetchContent)

project(Engine)

set(VENDOR_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor")
set(SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(HELPERS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Helpers")

set(SOURCES
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Core/os.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Core/platform.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Core/core.h"

    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Display/Display.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Display/Display.cpp"

    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Helpers/IO.h"

    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Platform/OpenGL/OpenGLDisplay.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Platform/OpenGL/OpenGLDisplay.cpp"
)

# Configure assets header file
configure_file(${HELPERS_DIR}/IO.h.in ${HELPERS_DIR}/IO.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# GLFW
FetchContent_Declare(
    GLFW    
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/glfw/glfw"
    GIT_TAG "3.3.2"
    GIT_SHALLOW ON
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(GLFW)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GLFW)

# glad
set(GLAD_DIR ${VENDOR_DIR}/glad)
add_library(glad ${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c)
target_include_directories(glad PRIVATE ${GLAD_DIR}/include)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${GLAD_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glad ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

# glm
FetchContent_Declare(
    glm
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git"
    GIT_TAG "0.9.9.8"
    GIT_SHALLOW ON
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(glm)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glm)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${SOURCE_DIR})

target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${SOURCE_DIR}/cpch.h")

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PRIVATE 
    CAFE_GML_ENABLED 
    _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
    GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE

    PUBLIC
    "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:CAFE_DEBUG>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:CAFE_RELEASE>"
)

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
```

Comment: Here is the complete manual, I'm sure you get success if you read it: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build.html

Comment: Please tell us what exact version/commit of glfw you are building against. That information matters.

Comment: I know you are saying you are using gitsubmodules but that doesn't help. Are you saying you are using latest at all times? A submodule to a specific commit/branch?

Comment: @cpp_guy_who_does_gfx i tried using the FetchContent CMake commands to fetch GLFW 3.3.2,which works in terms of fetching and linking, but i still get a lot of errors from GLFW, seemingly all of them from the objective-c (.m) files like coca_*.m and nsgl_*.m. I have XCode installed on my system which as far as i am concerned should have installed all the prerequisites for running OpenGL applications on my mac.

Comment: I've edited my answer with ideas. But before anything please double check and read the glfw documentation before anything. I know in the past myself, that quickly solves problems.

Answer (score 0):

This code you wrote is wrong:

```
set(GLFW_DIR ${VENDOR_DIR}/GLFW)
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL  "GLFW lib only")
set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL  "GLFW lib only")
add_subdirectory(${GLFW_DIR})
target_include_directories(Engine PRIVATE ${GLFW_DIR}/include)
target_link_directories(Engine PRIVATE ${GLFW_DIR}/src)
target_link_libraries(glfw)
```

All you need to do is the following:

```
add_subdirectory(${GLFW_DIR})
target_link_libraries(glfw)
```

Include directories are properly propagated up.

You question doesn't even tell us what version of GLFW you are using. Which is concerning.

Here is how I my recommendation of how you should use glfw in a modern cmake project:

```
# This command fetches glfw 3.3.2 from github
# Note the shallow parameter. This means it won't grab all the history.
FetchContent_Declare(glfw
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/glfw/glfw"
    GIT_TAG "3.3.2"
    GIT_SHALLOW ON
)

# Now make the glfw target available to link against
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(glfw)

target_link_libraries(foobar PRIVATE glfw)
```

Edit:

I'm using a relatively new version of cmake, so I definitely know all this works with cmake 3.15+

Also when I said the code you wrote was wrong I'm referring to how you dealt with include directories. Overriding the cache variables is fine.

Edit 2:

Hmm at this point it might be actual bugs in glfw. Building for apple is tricky so maybe it's a genuine fault of glfw.

Here's my recommendations.

1.) Use the latest commit of glfw and see if you still have the problem

2.) Try browsing the GLFW issues
https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues

This might be a known problem.

3.) Submit an issue/pull-request if you are correct the bug is coming from GLFW

Comment: i have changed the way i include GLFW, but i still get the same errors. I have edited my question with more of the cmakelists file included